# Is there a way to make git ignore your HOME setting?

Tags: git, windows

At work, HOME is set to point at a network drive. This drive is not available when I am outside the office.

One of the strengths of git is its distributed nature. But if I run git commands when I am not connected to corporate network then git complains that it cannot access my HOME folder to check git settings.

I hope to avoid setting environment settings back and forth when I am going in and out of office, but I attempted running cmd.exe to change the HOME environment variable in the set command and then run the bash start from the CMD window.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

I suspect that the act of logging in reset the variable because it still complained.

I only need to be working with the local repository when I am off the corporate network, if that opens up more options for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to have a specific problem with git commands here.  I would suggest either deleting this question and reposting it on Stack Overflow, or flagging it for migration.  See [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/40980) Note that this question is about the tool - its commands and arguments, not the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in Command Prompt:

```
set HOME=location of your choice
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

Note that the location must be specified using Windows's path syntax and without quotes (e.g. `C:\Users\Tormod`).  MSYS Bash automatically converts them into POSIX-like paths.

Now that you're in Bash, run:

```
ls -d "$HOME"
```

and see if it matches up what you originally set it.  If not, then it's likely your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` is overwriting the environment variables.